# clear limit on Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

It's possible to limit the results on a QuerySet by doing something like this:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.all()[:3]
```

Since the QuerySet is usually evaluated lazily, is it possible to remove this limit from the `qs` before it's iterated over?

I was hoping for something straight forward like `qs = qs[:]` or `qs = qs[0:]` but neither work.  So far the only thing I can get to work is `qs.query.clear_limits()` but I'm not really sure if that's part of the public API (I had to wade through Django source code to find it).

Comment: Nice find of `clear_limits()`. I'm not aware of a public API to do this. Perhaps there should be one - some other queryset methods have ways to 'reset', e.g. `.order_by()` and `select_related(None)`.

Comment: Of course that `clear_limits` is part of the public API, i have used it may times, and had worked fine for me needs

Answer (score 0):

Like Alasdair says, there doesn't seem to be a documented public API to clear the limits. Probably because it's not a very common thing to do.

Anyways, since it's not documented anywhere, I'd consider it as "internal" and subject to change without prior notice.